# Expose built-ins (e.g. `str`) in `pd.eval` or `df.eval`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, eval

By default, pandas's `eval` (both `pd.eval` and `df.eval`) captures `locals()` and `globals()` and makes them available as names in the expression, if prefixed with `@`. However, built-ins, such as `str`, are in neither. How can I expose them, to make them available (I guess with `@` as well) in the expressions? The expressions are (trusted) user supplied, so I can't just add the built-ins I need.

To give a concrete example, I'd like to get something like the following to run:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
res = df.eval('a.astype(@str)', engine='python')
```

Currently, this fails with: `pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: local variable 'str' is not defined`. My current workaround, while testing, is to manually add `str` to `globals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, put the type between quotes `'str'` :

```
res = df.eval("a.astype('str')", engine="python")
```

Output :

```
print(type(res.iat[0])) # <class 'str'>

print(res)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
Name: a, Length: 4, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to use normal quotes (to make string literals) then? E.g. `df.eval("a.astype('str') + '_blabla'", engine="python")` does not work. It fails with: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'object' and '<class 'str'>'`.

Comment: What about `df.eval("a.astype('str').add('_blabla')", engine="python")` ?

Comment: Found someone running into the same issue and it seems to just not be fixed lol: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47734

Comment: Your suggestion works as a workaround.